# Actor does not perform action when spawned?

Tags: unreal-4, spawning, blueprints

In the level blueprint I made a code so that after 5 seconds an NPC was spawned, it happens that it does nothing.

Only the NPC I added by the level editor acts correctly.

**Image of what happens:**

[image]

**Level Blueprint:**

[image]

**NPC Blueprint:**

[image]

I did a search, because I imagine that to solve this is to just modify the event to some of the type: **When created** or **when spawned**.

**Search:**

[image]

I also thought of something like an event involving the collision between the NPC and the ground, but I considered it silly.

**Link I found and at first I'm thinking that the solution may not be as simple as this:**

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/204154/event-dispatcher-on-a-spawned-actor.html

---

**EDIT 1 (Attempt based on ColdSteel's comment)**

**I added 2 impressions to see if the Event Begin Play was not even running:**

[image]

**The event is being started correctly and the loop is also:**

[image]

But the NPC does not go towards the target points and I do not know the reason.

Comment: Thats interesting... for me the begin play works for dynamically spawned actors: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/1465941-til-psa-spawnactor-will-immediately-call-beginplay-even-before-continuing-with-following-nodes

Comment: To verify if the BeginPlay is called add a PrintText node as a first node.

Comment: I added the print, it runs, but the rest of the code does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the NPC blueprint at the top of the screen, click **Class Defaults**, search for the **Auto Possess AI** option on the Pawn menu and select the **Placed in World or Spawned** option.

**Image to facilitate:**

[image]

I had help from user **Grot13** (https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/1624007-actor-does-not-perform-action-when-spawned).